# Nuxt 3 Hydration text mismatch in ... error when using shift()

Tags: nuxt.js, fetch, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I have a simple Nuxt 3 page:

```
<script setup>
const { data: loadedData, error } = await useAsyncData('posts', () => $fetch( `/api/posts`,
    {
        method: 'GET',
    }
));
</script>

<template>
  <div class="page-container">
      <ChildComponent
        :data="loadedData.data"
      />
  </div>
</template>
```

and my `<ChildComponent>` is:

```
<script setup>
defineComponent({
    name: 'ChildComponent'
})

const props = defineProps<UILayoutCategory>(); 
const data = props.data;
data.shift();
const block1 = data.slice(0,4);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="layout">
    {{ block1[0].title }}--{{ block1.length }}
</div>
</template>
```

So, when I am do `data.shift()` I am getting "Hydration text mismatch in..", and I see, that this `{{block1[0].title}}` has different text on server and on client.

What's wrong I do? I need to get data server side, make some actions with data (for example, delete first item, from array of posts, using shift(), or slice array of data), and render page server side.

When I remove `data.shift()` from code, error is gone.

My Nuxt3 app works in SSR mode:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  .....
});
```

Nuxt version is 3.9.3

Comment: I noticed, if I do like this `const data = [...props.data];` before using `data.shift();` error is gone too.

Comment: I wrote and explanation of what is happening as an answer, but I dont understand what are you trying to achieve with the shift() method? Why do you want to cut the first element before working with the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nuxt ssr the page is generated twice - first it is statically pre-rendered on server, then second time it is being "hydrated" with JavaScript features on client.

But it works with the same data scope. When you do `data.shift()` on a prop, you are modifying the `data` in parent component as well. So it is different during the first time Vue is mounting  on server and the second when mounting on client. So the rendered HTML is also different on server and on client. And this causes [hydration mismatch warning](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#hydration-mismatch) coming from underlying Vue.

When you do local copy of data inside component instance via `const data = [...props.data]` it works, because the data in parent remain intact and are passed as the same prop and thus treated the same on server and client.